# Any simple way to get the inverse laplace transforme of $\frac{p^3}{p^4+4w^4}$?

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

I can't succeed to find the inverse laplace transforme of : $\frac{p^3}{p^4+4w^4}$? , as this reason the fraction decomposition is hard for me to , wolfram alpha showed [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+transforme+of+(+p%5E3%2F(p%5E4%2B4w%5E4))) , but i don't know any simple way to do, any help ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform

The Bromwich integral is an approach one could use.

Comment: `Mathematica` says: $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{s^3}{s^4+4 w^4}\right](t)=\cos (t w) \cosh (t w)$